# How to save and restore window position in mfc

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc

I have a big program which loads and saves many projects, each project may have its own window layout(There are many controls and components on it).

- Each time when a project is closed, the layout is saved,
- The program restores the layout of the project next time it's loaded.

Currently, My solution is :

- When project is closed, I export all related reigistry in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\myprogram` to a local reg file in the project directory
- When project is loaded, the reg file is registered.

In this way I implement the function. However I think there must be much better solution, Can anyone give some advice?

Comment: If you are using a [CMultiPaneFrameWnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmultipaneframewnd-class), you can invoke its [SaveState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmultipaneframewnd-class#savestate) and [LoadState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmultipaneframewnd-class#loadstate) members. You need to provide more information in your question so that we can make better suggestions.

Comment: The program is a MDI program, `CMainFrame` is derived from `CMDIFrameWndEx`. most of the components are derived from `CDockablePane`